# IOC DI Global conception

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have two questions regarding IOC DI and overall conception.

First, I have one interface and 3 different implementations. I have my IOC that register all my interfaces / implementations at the start of my application (WPF). For two of those implementations I know which to resolve at loading time, but the other one I can't know until I have fully loaded the application. (I could guess which one to load, but it will be tricky and not very durable). So my question is, what I am missing here ? Since I don't want to resolve later in my code.

EDIT :

```
public interface IConfigurationManagement
    {
        void GetItem();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class1 is register with a TAG at the startup and resolved aswell because it's used by mainWindows (simplified)
    /// </summary>
    public class Class1 : IConfigurationManagement
    {
        public void GetItem()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class2 is register with a TAG at the startup and resolved aswell because it's used by mainWindows (simplified)
    /// </summary>
    public class Class2 : IConfigurationManagement
    {
        public void GetItem()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class1 is register with a TAG at the startup and resolved aswell because it's used by mainWindows (simplified)
    /// </summary>
    public class Class3 : IConfigurationManagement
    {
        public void GetItem()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I'm resolving mainWindows I can used

```
 Container.RegisterType<IMainWindowViewModel, MainWindowViewModel>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IConfigurationManagement>(TAG)));
```

But I will need to resolve Class3 later if the user could select "test mode" while the application is running. What I don't want is to access my IOC in my mainWindows class, so I don't know what to do.

The other question, is more about global conception. I have an interface that would have several implementations, but they should be living (injected) all together in my application so for me that means my interface is wrong and I should have another layer of interfaces ?

EDIT :

Currently I have something like this :

```
 public interface ISynoptique
    {
        void Run();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class1 is register with a TAG at the startup and resolved aswell because it's used by mainView (simplified)
    /// </summary>
    public class Class1 : ISynoptique
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class2 is register with a TAG at the startup and resolved aswell because it's used by mainView (simplified)
    /// </summary>
    public class Class2 : ISynoptique
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class1 is register with a TAG at the startup and resolved aswell because it's used by mainView (simplified)
    /// </summary>
    public class Class3 : ISynoptique
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

What I want is to have in MainWindowViewModel at least 3 instances of ISynoptique with 3 different implementations (Class1, Class2, Class3). Then for me here it's mistake in my conception if I need different implementations living in the same times, maybe they shouldn't have the same contract (interface).

Thanks, Thiebault.

Comment: Your question is too abstract. Please make it concrete by demonstrating the problem by showing code examples.

Comment: I've found my answers. First question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660854(v%3dpandp.20) and for the second question thanks to reading other blogs and docs I've found as I thought that I my interfaces were wrong.

Comment: EDITED comment : I have found two interresting articles on AutoFac doc that helps me for the first question  [here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/conditional-registration.html) they are also saying that after resolving I shouldn't update the container. With [this link](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) what I understand for my second question is that I miss some interfaces.